# Encriptar cadena de texto con SHA1

Tags: java, python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código en Java:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class EnconderPass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String password = "12345";
    byte[] newPassword = null;
    try {
        newPassword = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA").digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String encriptado = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(newPassword);
    System.out.println(encriptado);

}

}
```

Quiero reproducir los mismos resultados con Python 3, pero no se como "traducirlo". En este ejemplo Java la cadena **1235** equivale a **jLIjfQZ5yojbZGTqxg2pY0VROWQ=**

¿Cómo podría hacerlo en Python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Básicamente son dos bibliotecas a usar, [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) y [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html). Lo básico sería:

```
import hashlib
import base64


password = "12345"
newpassword = hashlib.sha1(password.encode()).digest()
encriptado = base64.b64encode(newpassword).decode('UTF-8')
print(encriptado)
```

**Salida:**

> jLIjfQZ5yojbZGTqxg2pY0VROWQ=

---

Solo queda meterlo en una clase y manejar las excepciones con un `try-except` si quieres una traducción "literal".

Comment: Solo agregaría un comentario adicional a la respuesta, SHA1 es un algoritmo de hashing inseguro que debiéramos evitar usar, la encriptación o más bien el cifrado, no se hace con él, sino con el algoritmo Base64.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ha funcionado.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho totalmente de acuerdo, se deberia usar un SHA2 como mínimo (como  SHA-256) o SHA3 (y hay quien considera que hay que ir abandonando SHA por completo).  La verdad es que el coste para romper el algoritmo ha bajado desde ser "imposible",  al rango de millones de $ y de ahí al  rango de los miles de $ en muy poco tiempo. Especialmente preocupante el reciente descubrimiento del ataque conocido como [SHAttered](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html), que evidencia que un ataque de colisión con aplicación real ya no es mera teoría.